# HTTP user/pass grab confusion

Tags: http, http-headers

First and foremost, my knowledge of this subject is limited. So i'm reaching out to learn more information..Any support would be greatly appreciated.

I've been trying to use wireshark to learn more about different network traffic, how protocols work, etc. Specifically, i've been trying to see how it's possible to sniff a user/pass off my friend's website (don't worry, he made it soley to help me and there are no inappropriate intentions). He made a basic HTTP website to ensure the minimum security. When i log in, on my computer, using my own username and pass, i can see that wireshark captures my information and i'm able to see my own username and pass.

However, if i use my phone to log in (w/ my own information), or if he logs in from his own computer, those username and passwords don't show up. Nothing shows up. I'm confused because we both expected that information to appear on wireshark like it did when i signed in from my computer.

As i mentioned above, my knowledge isnt deep with this topic, so any point of direction would be helpful!

Comment: This is off-topic for SO, but you might have better luck researching over on https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/. However, note that WireShark may not be able to see all traffic between all nodes -- it depends where WireShark is running, and one what networking devices, and how those devices are configured.

Answer (score 0):

> Wireshark lets the user put network interface controllers into
>   promiscuous mode (if supported by the network interface controller),
>   so they can see all the traffic visible on that interface including
>   unicast traffic not sent to that network interface controller's MAC
>   address.

If you've set up Wireshark to capture the traffic on your computer, you will see all the traffic between *your* network interface and the server hosting the website. 
However, Wireshark will not be able to capture the traffic from the network interface on your phone to the server.

If you set up Wireshark to capture the traffic on *the server itself*, then you will be able to see all the traffic in and out of it from *any device* used.

Comment: Interesting. Appreciate the reply. Apologize if this is obvious, but shouldn't i be able to see the traffic from my phone or my friend's, who is my roommate, computer; since all of those devices are using the same network interface. (en0). -- Separately, I tried filtering by the Server IP, but still nothing...

Comment: Each device has it's own network interface/adapter. It has nothing to do with the devices being all connected to the same router. Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I understand, you are capturing only the traffic from your network adapter?

Comment: My apologies on the very long delay here. I’ve been out of town for work. You are correct. I am only capturing the traffic from my computer/network adapter. I don’t know how I could set up wireshark to capture all the information from all the devices in the apartment?..